# convert array into DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np   
e = np.random.normal(size=100)  
e_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(e)
```

When I input the code above, I get this answer:

[image]

But how do I change the column name?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can add parameter columns or use `dict` with key which is converted to column name:

```
np.random.seed(123)
e = np.random.normal(size=10)  
dataframe=pd.DataFrame(e, columns=['a']) 
print (dataframe)
          a
0 -1.085631
1  0.997345
2  0.282978
3 -1.506295
4 -0.578600
5  1.651437
6 -2.426679
7 -0.428913
8  1.265936
9 -0.866740

e_dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'a':e}) 
print (e_dataframe)
          a
0 -1.085631
1  0.997345
2  0.282978
3 -1.506295
4 -0.578600
5  1.651437
6 -2.426679
7 -0.428913
8  1.265936
9 -0.866740
```

Comment: Great, thank you for your help ,the method  solves my problems.

Comment: How does it go when `e` is milt-dimensional array, e.g. suppose `e.shape= (7,5,3)`?

Answer (score 3):

In general you can use pandas rename function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). Given your dataframe you could change to a new name like this. If you had more columns you could also rename those in the dictionary. The 0 is the current name of your column

```
import pandas as pd    
import numpy as np   
e = np.random.normal(size=100)  
e_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(e)      

e_dataframe.rename(index=str, columns={0:'new_column_name'})
```

Comment: thank you very much. `pd.DataFrame(<array>)` is not only working for numeric elements, but working also for arrays containing string type elements.